# Adding "libpam" to initramfs recipe removes password from "extrausers" config

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am setting root password for my linux using the following in `local.conf` file:

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '\$6\$...'"
```

This works correctly, as expected.

But now, I found that in linux 5.10, to authenticate a user, I cannot check `/etc/shadow`, instead I need to use the `libpam` module. So, I did the following to add libpam to my linux image:

- In my intramfs recipe I added `libpam` to `PACKAGE_INSTALL`.
- Added `pam` in `DISTRO_FEATURES_append`

Now, when I flash this new image, the `root` user does not have any password. Adding libpam is somehow removing the password set using `extrausers`...
Is there a way to set the password in the image using libpam? Or is there something I am doing wrong when using extrausers and adding libpam to my image?

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't get an answer here and on github issues of `libpam` I gave up trying to make libpam work for me.

I decided to use the `/etc/shadow` file. I removed `extrausers` and instead set the password manually into the shadow file using the following:

```sh
ROOTFS_POSTINSTALL_COMMAND += "set_root_password;"
set_root_password () {
    sed -e "s/root::/root:\$6\$...:/" -i ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow
}
```

Now I don't need to use `libpam` and can keep authenticating users to my redfish server using the shadow file.